# Differences within Serivce, WorkManger and JobScheduler

Tags: android, background, task

Android imposed restrictions on background tasks since android 7.
Now we can use Service, JobScheduler, WorkManager.
What are differences within them?

Any has its own features and usage scenarioes?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager :

> WorkManager is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable,
>   asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or
>   the device restarts. The WorkManager API is a suitable and recommended
>   replacement for all previous Android background scheduling APIs,
>   including FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler.

Service is an component that is used to perform background operations. You can directly start service from activity or fragment using startService function.

JobScheduler is API that was used to schedule background tasks and services. Now it is replaced by WorkManager.